# git same file,different content in that file what will happen when git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 branches(master and development). in both branches, I have nginx conf. Now, in master branch, I need to have nginx.conf different from the nginx.conf that will be in development branch.

1) Can I have same file with different contents in multiple branches?

2) Sometimes I need to merge development into master branch. what will happen at that time? is it possible that nginx.conf from development branch got merged into master's nginx.conf and master's nginx.conf will change to development's nginx.conf ?

3) what is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

When you try your first merge of the files after they have diverged, git will try to bring over the file change from development to master.... you can amend the revision to revert that change or run with --no-commit so that you can do that reversal before committing.... after that happens, if the file **is not** changed on dev, git won't try to bring over the change from dev anymore when merging.... you should keep a sample file perhaps instead of the real one... but well, there you have what will happen from the "technical" POV.

Comment: Thanks . Could you comment a command which merges from development to master all the files, but not the one I want. for example I stand on master branch and I type. git merge development --dont-merge=nginx.conf (something like that).

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can do this, though: `git checkout master && git merge --no-commit development && git checkout HEAD -- some-file.txt && git commit -m "Here's a merge from development"`

Comment: At that point (from previous comment), HEAD is still pointing to the last revision of master because merge hasn't finished yet, so you are pulling that file from master _as is_.

Comment: any other way not to need that at all?

Answer (score 0):

I feel, it is better to create environment specific separate files like nginx.dev.conf, nginx.prod.conf, etc. and let your bundling tool worry about which file need to be picked up at what stage. It keeps things simple.

Having same file with different content across branches adds complexity during merge that has to be tackled with approach mentioned in the other answer here.